# Can I use form parserr to only perform table detection, and not table content extraction?

Tags: python, cloud-document-ai

I have a form parser processor setup, and I only need the bounding box of the detected page in my image, I don't need it to do the table text extraction as well. Is there anyway I can do this (if yes, will this take lesser latency somehow?). Currently it takes ~5 seconds per page. I'm using the python library.

I already have extraction set up properly using the python client library.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to only perform object detection (such as table detection) using the Document AI Form Parser.

There are a couple of options to get what you're looking for:

- In your post processing, you can search the [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) object response for the presence of the [`Document.pages.tables`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#table) field without getting the data from the table. Then you can access the bounding box information in the [`Table.layout`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document#Table.FIELDS.layout) field.
- If latency is a concern and you only need specific fields in the Document object response, you can provide a `fieldMask` in your processing request which lists the top-level fields that you want returned in the `Document` object. For example `pages.tables` would only return the `pages.tables` field.

  - https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.processors/process#body.request_body.FIELDS.field_mask
  - https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request#online-processor